# How do I move a percentage of files based on label with python?

Tags: python

I have a pandas data frame with each row corresponding to a .jpeg file and it's location.  I have made `train`, `test`, `validation` folders with folders each classification categories in said `train`, `test`, `validation`folders.

I now need to flow 80% of each category in the train folder, with 10% in the test and 10% in validation folder and once in there, each picture into its corresponding category folder (29 total categories).

Here is an example of the dataframe of files:

```
import pandas as pd
df = {'PictureFilename': ['0091240758-91931712.JPG','0091240791-91646592.JPG', '0091240791-91646593.JPG']
      , 'Target': ['Detached Structure','Address Verification', 'Other']
      , 'location': ['D:\CIS inspection images 0318\Photos\0091240758-91931712.JPG'
                     ,'D:\CIS inspection images 0318\Photos\0091240791-91646592.JPG'
                     ,'D:\CIS inspection images 0318\Photos\0091240791-91646593.JPG']}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df)
df_1
```

For the sake of simplicity, the first file would go into

`D:\CIS inspection images 0318\Photos\Train\Detached structure`,

the second in

`D:\CIS inspection images 0318\Photos\Train\Address Verification`

and the third in

`D:\CIS inspection images 0318\Photos\Train\Other`

On the actual problem, I have just over 3 million photos total and they will flow into the train, test, validation based on the percentage splits.

Is this possible with python?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out.  I decided to move all the the training folders, then iterate from the training folders to the validation and test folders.

To move all to the training folder:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    for index, row in labels.iterrows():
        try:
            shutil.move(row['location'], row['destination'])
        except:
            pass
```

Then the next is to move 10% to the testing folder:

```
#move 10% to test folder
for i, r in label_move_count.iterrows():
    n=0
    for index, row in labels.iterrows():
        if row['target'] == r['target']:
            #n+=1
            if n < row['testcount']:
                try:
                    shutil.move(row['destination']+'\\'+row['PictureFilename'], row['test_destination'])
                    print(n, row['target'])
                    n+=1
                except:
                    pass
        else:
            pass
```

Then I repeated the above to move to the validation folder.  This moves over 3 million photos to 28 separate class folders within a training, validation and test folder.